# C programming exit from main if function return error

Tags: c

Please see this:

```
int f();
int g();

int main()
{
   f(); 
   g(); 

   return 0;
}

int f()
{
   // In case of fail
   return 1;
}

int g()
{
   return 0;
}
```

So in case i have an `error` in `f()` how can i immediately exit from `main` without run `g()` and return `0` from `main`.

What is the right way to do that ?

Comment: use `exit(exit code);` function to exit at any point of time.

Comment: What is the different between return 1 and exit(1); ?

Comment: This is largely a matter of taste.  Some people prefer to put a label on the return, and if `f()` fails, do a `goto label;` (note that this method is polarizing).  Some people prefer to embed the error checking in if/else structures `if(f() fails){/*handle it*}else if(g() fails){...}`).  I've also seen it done with a status variable: `int status; status = f(); if(status == ok){status = g();}  ...`

Comment: `exit` can be called from anywhere in the program. It is used as emergency exit when there is no hope of recovery. Whereas `return` reverts to the calling function. But in the case of `main` you can simply write `if (f()) { return 0; }`

Comment: In the context of `main()`, `return` and `exit()` look similar (unless `main` is recursive).  If you think about error handling within a function (like `f()`) you'll see the difference:  if an internal step in `f()` fails, you want to report the error to it's caller (which `main()` in this case).  if `f()` instead calls `exit()`, the program ends.  So `exit()` is generally less appropriate for reusable library routines, where the expectataion is that they will report any errors to their caller, rather than closing the program.

Answer (score 2):

You can exit from the application like below:

```
int main()
{
  if (f())//if statement does not require `}` if it has only one statement. Here it is only `exit(1)` statement.
    exit(1);// error exit, you can use return 1; as well. Because here f() returns 1
  g();
  exit(0);  // correct execution exit. You can use return 0; as well.
}
```

Now you can check the exit status like below:-

UNIX/LINUX
`echo $?`

WINDOWS
`echo %ERRORLEVEL%`

Comment: As the `main` should return an `int` I am contemplating if the `exit(0)` at the end should be replaced by `return`

Comment: @sjsam exit(0) will return a value as 0 which can be check with $? and exit(1) return 1 from the program.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for that point.. I see that both will call the registered atexit handlers and then terminate the program.

Comment: If you call `exit()` from the main part of the `if` statement, there's no need to use an `else` block.

Comment: @ilkkachu, Agree. I have modified the answer as per your advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
int f();
int g();

int main()
{
  int value;
   if(!f()){

 return 0;
 }else{
 value= g();
    } 

 return value;
 }

int f()
 {

   if(stat=='correct'){
    // In case of success
   return 1;
  }
   else{ // In case of fail
    return 0;}
  } 

  int g()
 {
    if(stat=='correct'){
    // In case of success
   return 1;
  }
    else{ // In case of fail
    return 0;}
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way:

```
int main()
{
   if(!f()){
     return 0;
   }else{
     g()
   }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation too.. :-)

Comment: Aside: you don't need an `else` after a `return`, and there is `;` missing after `g()`

Comment: else is not after return, else is for if statement. missing semicolon is not the question he/she asked. The main point how to put if/else statement.